# PK Violation (of other entity) when adding inserting new entity and setting a reference to other entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

I am using Entity Framework 4.3 and I am trying to reference an existing entity by setting the navigation property when creating a new entity, however when i call save EF complains that there is a PK violation in the table for which i set the navigation property to (i.e. it is creating a new record as opposed to a reference!).

How can i attach to an existing POCO as opposed to referencing it and having EF trying to create a new database record (but not simply use an ID, ideally i would like to reference an actual entity that came from another query)?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

```
public class BusinessUnit
{
    public int BusinessUnitID { get; set; }
    public ExternalPlugin AccountsDataSourceModule { get; set; }
    public ExternalPlugin OptionalContactsDataSourceModule { get; set; }
}

public BusinessUnit NewBusinessUnit(string name, ExternalPlugin accountsModuleId = null, ExternalPlugin contactsModuleId = null)
{
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork();

    BusinessUnit unit = new BusinessUnit();
    unit.CompanyName = name;
    unit .AccountsDataSourceModule = accountsModuleId; // this causes a problem
    unit .OptionalContactsDataSourceModule = contactsModuleId; // as does this
    unitOfWork.BusinessUnitRepository.Insert(unit);

    unitOfWork.Save();
    return unit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *attach* the existing entities to the context:

```
BusinessUnit unit = new BusinessUnit();
unit.CompanyName = name;

unitOfWork.ExternalPluginRepository.Attach(accountsModuleId);
unitOfWork.ExternalPluginRepository.Attach(contactsModuleId);

unit.AccountsDataSourceModule = accountsModuleId;
unit.OptionalContactsDataSourceModule = contactsModuleId;
unitOfWork.BusinessUnitRepository.Insert(unit);
```

...where `unitOfWork.ExternalPluginRepository.Attach(ExternalPlugin plugin)` must do:

```
context.ExternalPlugins.Attach(plugin);
```

I expect that all repositories use the same context instance. `Attach` tells EF that the plugins already exist in the database and avoids an INSERT of those entities.

**Edit**

If you get the error message...

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

...it means that you have an entity that is attached to more than one context instance at the same time. You can avoid that in most cases by disposing the context always when you don't need it anymore. Your code sample does not follow this good practice. It rather should look like this:

```
public BusinessUnit NewBusinessUnit(string name,
    ExternalPlugin accountsModuleId = null,
    ExternalPlugin contactsModuleId = null)
{
    using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {
        BusinessUnit unit = new BusinessUnit();
        unit.CompanyName = name;

        unitOfWork.ExternalPluginRepository.Attach(accountsModuleId);
        unitOfWork.ExternalPluginRepository.Attach(contactsModuleId);

        unit.AccountsDataSourceModule = accountsModuleId;
        unit.OptionalContactsDataSourceModule = contactsModuleId;
        unitOfWork.BusinessUnitRepository.Insert(unit);

        unitOfWork.Save();

        return unit;
    }
}
```

At the end of the `using` block the `Dispose` method of the `unitOfWork` is called automatically. To get this working (and compiling as well) you need to derive your `IUnitOfWork` interface from `IDisposable` and implement it in the concrete `UnitOfWork` class:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    // ...
}

public class ConcreteUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContext _context;
    // I assume that you have a member for the DbContext in this class
    // ...

    // implementation of IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
            _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Slauma, I am running with the above, works perfectly for one bit of code, on another i am retreving an entity and setting to a member and then get the following error:

"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

The code looks identical but is obviously doing different things what causes this and any idea how i can get around it? Thanks.

Comment: @g18c: See my Edit. If this doesn't remove the error, you need to provide more details where the error occurs. Better ask a new question then because the problem is unrelated to your original question.